# How do I measure CPU cache and prefetch misses in JavaScript engines?

Tags: javascript, v8, cpu-cache, javascriptcore, chakracore

I want a command-line way to evaluate low-level contributors to lower performance-per-watt of Node.js applications. Namely, L1, L2, and prefetch cache misses of JIT-generated native code, as well as the JIT/GC/interpteter of the JavaScript runtime itself.

JavaScriptCore, v8, and ChakraCore all supply commandline REPLs for running benchmarks. What profiler(s) can I run on Intel-, AMD-, and ARMv6-based hardware to gather these statistics with reasonable accuracy? I'd prefer to have a way to do this across at least two operating systems: Windows, Mac, and/or Linux.

Comment: i've not seen anything like that before, in ~10 years of hardcore js dev...

Comment: @dandavis you were actually a mediumcore js dev.  this is hardcore

Comment: I don't see how this is specific to JS. Just profile the js engine like you would with any other program.

Comment: some profilers can't give accurate information for dynamically-generated native code, only compile-time code with specific symbols available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V8 and the Linux `perf` tool support each other, see [the documentation](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/V8-Linux-perf-Integration). If you have a very recent system (IIRC kernel >= 4.4 and perf >= 4.10), you can skip the steps for compiling your own kernel and `perf`.

Comment: unfortunately, this wouldn't allow me to evaluate differences between Linux, Windows, or MacOS implementations. JIT and GC operates quite differently between platforms depending on threading model, native locking mechanisms, etc.

Comment: JIT and GC are operating system agnostic; minor differences in the locking/threading primitives that each platform provides are abstracted away. Linux `perf` is what the V8 team uses for low-level analysis; if any better/additional solution exists we'd like to hear about it :-)

Comment: exceptions, trampolines, how JIT'd code is mapped into memory pages, etc is actually quite different between MacOS, Windows, and Linux from my understanding. am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a misunderstanding. I'm not aware of any significant differences. The exception mechanism is the same everywhere. Code objects are put onto the heap in the same way everywhere. I don't know what trampolines you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Quoting their FAQ, "Valgrind can handle dynamically generated code, so long as none of the generated code is later overwritten by other generated code".

It is also supported on various platforms including X86/Linux, X86/Darwin etc

Comment: Since V8 puts generated code onto the garbage-collected heap, code objects do move around, and the same memory address may very well be used for different code objects over time.